# Create c++ project on Xcode with allegro5

Tags: c++, xcode, allegro

I have tried recently to create a c++ project on Xcode using allegro5.
I had no trouble creating a c++ project, but I encountered some difficulties when trying to use allegro.

I followed the following tutorial to install and bound allegro to Xcode : 
http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=OSX,_Xcode_4,_Framework

The first problem here is that this tutorial does not use c++ project but a cocoa application.
But still, I followed the step and at the end, when I tried to build, Xcode returned the following error : 'allegro5/allegro.h' file not found

I have ben trying to find on google for any help, but without success.

If anyone could help me, it would be great.

Thank you